# Implicit cast to runnable interface when using threads via anonymous class?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, casting

When I use this constructor of the thread class : Thread(Runnable target) and use an anonymous class inside the constructor , can we say that an implicit cast happens in which my object of anonymous class is casted to runnable interface ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Every anonymous class has base class or interface, and that class or interface must extend `Runnable`, so that no cast is required, implicit or explicit.

But if your base class does not extend `Runnable`, then compile error occur:

```
    new Thread(new Object(){});
    new Thread(new Serializable(){});
```